# How to apply FULL_CONTROL ACL to a bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, acl

I'm new in S3 buckets and currently I'm testing permissions. I applied following ACL for the bucket (owned by user1) so I expected user2 is able to see it and delete but it didn't happen. Could you tell my what is wrong?

```
{
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "USER1",
        "ID": "USER1"
    },
    "Grants": [
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "DisplayName": "USER1",
                "ID": "USER1",
                "Type": "CanonicalUser"
            },
            "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
        },
                        {
            "Grantee": {
                "DisplayName": "USER2",
                "ID": "USER2",
                "Type": "CanonicalUser"
            },
            "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using aws s3api to set this.

Answer (score 0):

Using S3 ACL, you grant permission to an AWS account using the email address or the canonical user ID. Your ACL shows how permissions are granted on a newly created bucket to two AWS accounts i.e. USER1 and USER2

Using the profile of any user with access to S3 in the USER2 account, you should be able to list contents of newly created bucket in USER1 account using below AWS CLI command:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket <<newlycreatedbucketname in USER1 account>> --profile <<user in USER2 account>>
```

For more details, please refer to [Access control list (ACL) overview](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/acl-overview.html)